# Adjust figure yellow bricks model - python

Tags: python, pandas, yellowbrick

I am trying to adjust the axes limits on a yellow bricks figure. However, I can't seem to adjust it. I can change axes labels and titles but not the limits. It works if I don't render the figure with `visualizer.show()` but then I lose labels, titles, legend etc.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder, LabelEncoder
from yellowbrick.classifier import ROCAUC
from yellowbrick.datasets import load_game
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, y = load_game()

X = OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform(X)
y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim([-0.05, 1.0])
ax.set_ylim([0.0, 1.05])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,6))

model = RidgeClassifier()
visualizer = ROCAUC(model, classes=["win", "loss", "draw"], ax = ax)

visualizer.fit(X_train, y_train)       
visualizer.score(X_test, y_test)        
visualizer.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the `visualizer.show()` method, you can try calling the `visualizer.finalize()` method and then accessing the underlying matplotlib axes to change the limits. You are also overwriting `ax` which wasn't doing you any favours either.

Here is the full code example:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder, LabelEncoder
from yellowbrick.classifier import ROCAUC
from yellowbrick.datasets import load_game
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, y = load_game()

X = OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform(X)
y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,6))

model = RidgeClassifier()
visualizer = ROCAUC(model, classes=["win", "loss", "draw"], ax=ax)

visualizer.fit(X_train, y_train)       
visualizer.score(X_test, y_test)        
visualizer.finalize()   
ax.set_xlim([-0.05, 1.0])
ax.set_ylim([0.0, 1.05])
```